aiogram 2.25.1 выдача мута пользователю выдается навсегда
async def mute_user(self, message: types.Message, chat_id, user_id, mute_end: datetime | timedelta):
"""Выдача мута"""
await message.bot.restrict_chat_member(
                    chat_id=chat_id,
                    user_id=user_id,
                    permissions=types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False),
                    until_date=mute_end
                )

суть в выдаче мута пользователю, проблемы нет пользователь получает мут но почему то навсегда, хотя вроде как until_date принимает время в которое пользователь размутится, но это не срабатывает
в time предается
SET mute_end = last_message_time + INTERVAL '1 second' * mute_duration;

где last_message_time - время последнего сообщения
mute_duration - время мута обычно 1 минута

«в time предается» — откуда как передаётся? В чём связь между mute_end и time?

из таблицы подтягивается, это одно и тоже, название разное было, уже исправил

Вы проверяли, что этот ваш mute_end в принципе содержит ожидаемое вами и правильное время? С учётом того, что «правильное» — это в диапазоне от 30 секунд до 366 дней относительно текущего времени

да, проверял, там ровно 1 минута.
В документации видел что если будет меньше 30 то выдается навсегда.
